# Изменение формата даты в MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, дата

Есть приложения с утерянным исходным кодом и выполняющим запросы к базам данных, в которых дата указывается как 'гггг.мм.дд'. Базы были перенесены на новый сервер, но в нем формат данных стоит как 'гггг.дд.мм' и соответственно выдаются ошибки преобразования VARCHAR к DATETIME.

```
Additional information: Преобразование типа данных varchar в тип данных datetime привело к выходу значения за пределы диапазона.
```

Поскольку сами приложения я изменить не могу, возникает вопрос, можно ли изменить формат даты в самом сервере?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел следующее решение: Тип данных datetime не удовлетворяет стандартам ANSI и ISO 8601, и интерпретирует строку входящих данных varchar в datetime в зависимости от языковых настроек.

В таблице sys.syslanguages дано более подробное описание языковых настроек, в том числе как интерпретируются строки в дату в столбце [dateformat] (mdy, dmy, ymd, ydm, myd и dym):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190303.aspx

Выполнив запрос получаем список языков:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages
```

Текущий язык можно узнать следующим запросом:

```
select @@language 
или
EXEC sp_configure "default language"
```

Соответственно, нужно изменить язык на подходящий, что бы строки интерпретировались правильно. Можно поменять как язык сервера, так и язык конкретного пользователя. Для изменения языка пользователя использовался следующий запрос, который решил проблему:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187378.aspx

```
ALTER LOGIN User WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = Svenska;
```

Если надо поменять язык на всем сервере:
http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/11/change-default-language-for-sql-server.html

```
EXEC sp_configure "default language", <langid из syslanguage>
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

Answer (score 1):

гляньте тут - возможно поможет http://www.sql.ru/faq/faq_topic.aspx?fid=109

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, информация полезная, но к сожалению требует доступ к самим SQL запросам программы и соответственно надо править исходный код, которого нет.

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливаем нужный формат через `SET DATEFORMAT`, далее всё делается штатными средствами:

```sql
DECLARE @testDate VARCHAR(10);

SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SET @testDate = '20.01.2016';
SELECT CAST(@testDate AS DATETIME), CAST(@testDate AS DATE);

SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
SET @testDate = '2016-01-20';
SELECT CAST(@testDate AS DATETIME), CAST(@testDate AS DATE);
```

Comment: топикастер же написал, что выполнить SET DATEFORMAT у него нет возможности.

Comment: Инструкция SET DATEFORMAT действует только на текущую сессию. Запуск программы пользователем создает новую сессию, так же как это может делать и любой новый запрос внутри программы в случае переподключений. Поэтому прописывать SET DATEFORMAT надо в запросах именно внутри программы. Исходных кодов нет, поэтому данный вариант отпадает по условию вопроса.